# ¿Cómo hacer que el carousel funcione para multiples secciones jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo realizado un `carousel` que me permite deslizar entre varios productos de manera horizontal e infinito o circular, además de eso cuando no existen más de 4 artículos los botones para deslizar de izquierda o derecha se ocultan, esta acción también no funciona dado a que a contabiliza todos los `item` de la página.

Entonces, como puedo realizar a que estos comportamiento funcionen de manera individual por cada `sección` de `carousel` que se encuentra en la misma página, por ejemplo la página principal.

Los errores comunes, no me permite deslizar los productos en los otros `carousel` no me oculta los botones en otras secciones que solo estén menos de 4 artículos, dado que solo esta validando o tomando en cuenta la primera sección del `carousel`.

Este es mi código y, el código completo aquí https://jsfiddle.net/cdunbf4y/ dado a que SO me muestra un mensaje de error que he sobrepasado los 3000 caracteres.

```js
var direction_slider = "up";
    var current_step = 0;
    var scroll_product = false;
    var scroll = -1;

$(function(){
    $(".carousels").each(function(){
        var numItems = $(this).find("div.item").length;
        if (numItems <= 4) {
            $(this).find('.nav-btn').css('display','none');
        }
    });

    $('.carousel-right').click(function() {
        //.last().remove()
        $('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
    })
    $('.carousel-left').click(function() {
        $('.item.product').first().insertAfter($('.item.product').last());
    })

    // vars for clients list carousel
    var $product_carousel = $('.slider');
    var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
    var product_width = (products * 140); // 140px width for each client item
    $product_carousel.css('width',product_width);

    var rotating = true;
    //var product_speed = 1800;
    //var see_products = setInterval(rotateClients, product_speed);

    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            rotating = true;
        }
    }, '.carousel');

    /*SLIDER CON MOVIMIENTO SLIDER CAROUSEL ANIMADO
  function rotateClients() {
        if(rotating != false) {
            if (direction_slider == "up") {
                rotateClientsUp();
            if (++current_step == $(".slider .item").length) direction_slider = "down";
            } else {
                rotateClientsDown();
                if (--current_step == 0)  direction_slider = "up";
            }
        }
    }

    function rotateClientsUp() {
        var $last   = $('.slider .item:last');
        $last.remove().css("margin-left", "-140px");
        $(".slider").prepend($last);
        $last.animate({ 'margin-left': '0' }, 600);
    }

    function rotateClientsDown() {
        var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
        $first.animate({ 'margin-left': '-140px' }, 600, function() {
            $first.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
            $('.slider .item:last').after($first);
        });
    }*/
    $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        scroll_product = true;
        scroll = e.pageX;
        event.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        scroll_product = false;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
        var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
        for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
            var $last  = $('.slider .item:last');
            if (dir == "up") {
                $last.prependTo(".slider");
            } else {
                $first.appendTo(".slider");
            }
        }
        $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (scroll_product) {
            $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(" + ( e.pageX - scroll ) +"px, 0)")
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
.carousels {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.slider {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.1rem;
    width: 100% !important;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.carousel-left {
    left: 10px;
}
.carousel-right {
    right: 0px;
}
.nav-btn {
    top: 25%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(213 217 217 / 50%);
}
.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: #F7FAFA;
}
.item {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.item.product .c-rating {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
.item.product .rating {
    margin-bottom: .2rem;
}
.item.product .total-avg span {
    margin-right: .4rem;
    color: #be5a0e;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.item.product .valuations {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    color: #73726c;
}
.item.product .valuations span {
    font-size: .8em;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.thumbnails {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbnails img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.topic-1 .price label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.topic-1 .price em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #17aa1c;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="wrapp">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="heading mini-title">
                <h2>Nuevos productos</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product category-info">
                            <div class="banner-info">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                                    <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                                    <span>Source Now</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Tú producto aquí 8</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Tú producto aquí 7</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Tú producto aquí 6</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Tú producto aquí 5</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapp">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item ads-store">
                            <div class="adsowners">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h4>¡Ofertas!</h4>
                                    <h5>En la tienda Motorsykler</h5>
                                    <img src="https://img.joomcdn.net/181508ee57b71b20f26b4a8a14a79f142b9165af_176_176.png">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo de HTML sobre el que está trabajando ese Javascript? Ayudaría mucho a entender el problema

Comment: @PabloLozano revisando la pregunta está este enlace https://jsfiddle.net/cdunbf4y/ que es el código completo, ahí está la estructura HTML

Comment: He simplificado el HTML, eliminando elementos que no son relevantes del documento, para poder crear el fragmento completo aquí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dices, cuando cuentas los items con

```
var numItems = $('div.item').length;
```

Tienes el total. Pero lo que quieres es el número de items de cada carousel, así que veamos como podemos solucionar esto.

Para empezar, no puedes repetir valores de ID, por definición han de ser únicos. Por tanto he cambiado un poco los botones:

```
<button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
<button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Por tanto el CSS lo he modificado acorde a esto.

Podemos entonces buscar los carousel y, para cada uno, buscar sus items. El resto del código no cambiaría mucho, es lo que tienes sustituyendo `$('...')` por `$carousel.find('...')` para hacer una búsqueda de elementos "local" al carousel actual:

```js
const carousels = $('.carousel');
console.log(`Tenemos ${carousels.length} carousels`);
carousels.each((index, carousel) => {
  const $carousel = $(carousel);
  const numItems = $carousel.find('.item-price').length;
  console.log(`El carousel ${index} tiene ${numItems} items`);

  if (numItems <= 4) {
    $carousel.find('button.nav-btn').css('display', 'none');
    console.log('ocultando botones');
    return; //no añadimos listeners para este carousel
  }
  const $items = $carousel.find('.item.product');
  $carousel.find('.carousel-right').click(function() {
  
    $items.last().insertBefore($items.first());
  })
  $carousel.find('.carousel-left').click(function() {
    $items.first().insertAfter($items.last());
  })

  // vars for clients list carousel
  var $product_carousel = $carousel.find('.slider');
  var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
  var product_width = (products * 140); // 140px width for each client item
  $product_carousel.css('width', product_width);

  var rotating = true;
  //var product_speed = 1800;
  //var see_products = setInterval(rotateClients, product_speed);

  $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      rotating = true;
    }
  }, '#carousel');

  let scroll_product;
  $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
    scroll_product = true;
    scroll = e.pageX;
    event.preventDefault();
  }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    scroll_product = false;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
    var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
    for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
      var $first = $carousel.find('.slider .item:first');
      var $last = $carousel.find('.slider .item:last');
      if (dir == "up") {
        $last.prependTo($product_carousel);
      } else {
        $first.appendTo($product_carousel);
      }
    }
    $carousel.css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
  }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (scroll_product) {
      $carousel.css("transform", "translate(" + (e.pageX - scroll) + "px, 0)")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.slider {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.1rem;
    width: 100% !important;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.carousel-left {
    left: 10px;
}
.carousel-right {
    right: 0px;
}
.nav-btn {
    top: 25%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(213 217 217 / 50%);
}
.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: #F7FAFA;
}
.item {
    width: 25px;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.item.product .c-rating {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
.item.product .rating {
    margin-bottom: .2rem;
}
.item.product .total-avg span {
    margin-right: .4rem;
    color: #be5a0e;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.item.product .valuations {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    color: #73726c;
}
.item.product .valuations span {
    font-size: .8em;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.thumbnails {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbnails img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.topic-1 .price label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.topic-1 .price em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #17aa1c;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.rating {
  display:none;
}
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapp">
  <div class="deals">
    <div class="heading mini-title">
      <h2>Fashion</h2>
      <div class="rule"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel relative">
      <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
      <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
      <div>
        <div class="slider" style="width: 2100px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 7</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 6</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 5</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 8</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 7</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 6</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="assets/img/website/catalog/builder.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 5</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 8</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 7</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 6</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 5</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 8</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapp-2">
  <div class="deals-2">
    <div class="heading mini-title">
      <h2>Fashion</h2>
      <div class="rule"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel relative">
      <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
      <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
      <div>
        <div class="slider" style="width: 2100px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 7</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 6</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item product">
            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
              <div class="thumbnails image">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
              </div>
              <div class="box topic-1">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                  <h2>Tú producto aquí 5</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="price right">
                  <label></label>
                  <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="item category-info">
            <div class="banner-info">
              <a href="">
                <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                <span>Source Now</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, hasta aquí parece estar todo muy bien `console.log(`El carousel ${index} tiene ${$items.length} items`);`  menos de 4 itemes tengo que ocultar el botón que desplaza el carrusel y aplicar esta regla `if (numItems <= 4) {
  $('button.nav-btn').css('display','none');
 }`  solo para los `slider` que tengan menos de `4` artículos (`.item`)

Comment: Pero lo más importante en sí, no era esto, sino que el `slider carrusel` no funciona para los múltiples `slider carrusel` https://jsfiddle.net/8nqtz5sy/ si damos click en los botones `< >`  del primer `slider` funciona al igual que el `mouseup` pero en el segundo `slider carrusel` no funciona

Comment: No he querido meter todo el código en la respuesta para centrarme en la idea global, pero en principio sólo tienes que añadir tu lógica donde puse el comentario *hacemos cosas*, usando `$carousel.find` en lugar de `$`, eso haría que las búsquedas sean locales a cada uno, con lo que podrías activar o desactivar los botones en cada uno independientemente

Comment: Lo observe detalladamente amigo, pero parece que das estilos a los `div .item` entonces me perdí en como ocultar los botones cuando el `carrusel` tenga menos de 4 productos.

Comment: eso no era más que un ejemplo, actualizaré la respuesta cuendo tenga un rato para adaptarla más a tu lógica

Comment: Intente hacerlo así pero oculta los botones a todos los `slider carrusel` https://jsfiddle.net/kdc3u8j2/ pensé que esto sería la clave `${$items.length}` ya que en `console` imprimía la cantidad de `div  .item` entonces pensé que podía hacer esto `var numItems = $items.length;` para luego usar la condición `if (numItems <= 4) {}` pero no, me engañe, pensé que lo mismo que se imprimía sería lo mismo pero ya fuera de la la `console`  se da otros datos. De todos modo gracias :)

Comment: Por cierto el `mouseup` de la manito que puede deslizar el `slider carrusel` funciona en ambos, el problema es que los mueve ambos, cada acción debe ser individual y no afectar a los otros `slider carrusel`

Comment: Actualizado con algunos bugs solucionados

Comment: @PabloLozano A mi también ayúdeme :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485832/c%c3%b3mo-enviar-datos-autom%c3%a1ticamente-al-manipular-el-campo-input-al-igual-que-los

Comment: @PabloLozano No me funciona amigo :/ anteriormente me habían recomendado cambiar los `id` por `class` ya lo hice, actualice mi pregunta con los cambios y la estructura ``HTML` organizada y, los nuevos estilos `css` agregados. En este caso existen dos estructuras para dos `slider` como se puede observar en el último no todos tienen precio, por eso cuando intente contar para ocultar los botones contaba esto: `item` `<div class="item product">` ya que es el contenedor del producto cuantas cajitas de esas existían dentro del contenedor `<div class="slider">`

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por tu tiempo :) por cierto en el código de su respuesta los botones del slider parece funcionar una sola vez, no es infinito, si observa en mi nueva actualización el slider es infinito, para saber que termino que ya no hay más producto existe una cajita especial que es esta `<div class="item product category-info">` con eso el usuario se guía :) de que ya no hay nuevos productos.

Comment: @PabloLozano Ya he solucionado el problema de ocultar los botones por `.item`

Answer (score 0):

En casos como éste, donde requieres encapsular el control, conviene usar [*Componentes Web*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Web_Components).
La primer ventaja es que reduces significativamente la cantidad de html usando `<template>`; como observarás en el ejemplo, es prácticamente el mismo código que proporcionaste, simplemente metí en una plantilla html la estructura del carrusel y en otra plantilla la estructura para cada producto, de tal manera que en tu html sólo tienes que agregar elementos `<my-carousel>` y `<my-carousel-item>`. Con ayuda de elementos marcadores de posición `<slot>` podemos enviar a la plantilla los datos particulares de cada producto:

```
<my-carousel id="carrusel1">
   <div slot="carousel-content" class="carousel relative">
      <my-carousel-item>
         <a slot="liga" href="producto1">
            <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 1">
            <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 1</h2>
            <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
            <span slot="valoracion">(1)</span>
            <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$1,00</em>
         </a>
      </my-carousel-item>
   </div>
</my-carousel>
```

Al momento de registrar el componente en el navegador con `customElements.define()`, declaramos su correspondiente clase controladora que hereda `HTMLElement` y será instanciada para cada elemento `<my-carousel>`, es decir, cada carrusel tendrá su controlador independiente.
La magia ocurre en el método de preparación `ready()`, donde controlamos la visualización de los botones y vinculamos sus clicks con los métodos `izquierda()` y `derecha()`.

```js
   customElements.define( 'my-carousel'
                        ,  class extends HTMLElement {
                              #direction_slider = 'up';
                              #current_step = 0;
                              #scroll_product = false;
                              #scroll = -1;
                              #rotating = true;
                              #container;

                              constructor() {
                                 super();
                                 let template = document.getElementById('carouselTemplate');
                                 
                                 const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
                                                        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
                                 
                                 setTimeout(this.ready())
                              }

                              ready(){
                                 
                                 this.#container = this.firstElementChild
                                 
                                 let izq = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button#carousel-left')
                                 let der = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button#carousel-right')
                                 
                                 if( this.#container.querySelectorAll('my-carousel-item').length <= 4 ){
                                    izq.style.display = 'none'
                                    der.style.display = 'none'
                                 }else{
                                    izq.addEventListener( 'click', this.izquierda.bind(this) )
                                    der.addEventListener( 'click', this.derecha.bind(this) )
                                 }
                                 
                              }

                              izquierda(e){
                                 var first = this.#container.firstElementChild
                                 var last  = this.#container.lastElementChild
                                 this.#container.removeChild(last)
                                 this.#container.insertBefore(last,first)
                              }

                              derecha(e){
                                 var first = this.#container.firstElementChild
                                 this.#container.removeChild(first)
                                 this.#container.appendChild(first)
                              }
                           }
                        );
   customElements.define( 'my-carousel-item'
                        ,  class extends HTMLElement {
                              constructor() {
                                 super();
                                 let template = document.getElementById('carouselContentTemplate');
                                 const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
                                                        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
                              }
                           }
                        );
```

```css
   my-carousel{
      width: 100%;
      padding: 1em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 1400px;
      margin-left: auto;
      display: block;
   }

   my-carousel-item img{
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }

   my-carousel-item h2[slot=nombre-producto],
   my-carousel-item span[slot=calificacion],
   my-carousel-item span[slot=valoracion]{ 
      display: block; 
   }

   my-carousel-item span[slot=valoracion]{
      font-size: .8em;
      color: #73726c;
   }

   em.item-price {
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #17aa1c;
      font-weight: 600;
   }
```

```html
<template id="carouselTemplate">
   <style>
      :host{ position: relative; }

      .slider{
         display: grid;
         grid-gap: 0.1rem;
         width: 200%;
         grid-auto-flow: column;
         transform: translate(0px, 0px);
      }
      #carousel-left { left: 10px; }
      #carousel-right { right: 10px; }
      .nav-btn {
         top: 25%;
         width: 40px;
         height: 45px;
         z-index: 100;
         cursor: pointer;
         position: absolute;
         border-radius: 8px;
         background-color: white;
         border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
         cursor: pointer;
         text-align: center;
         vertical-align: middle;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(213 217 217 / 50%);
      }
      .nav-btn:hover {
         background-color: #F7FAFA;
      }

   </style>

   <button id="carousel-left" class="nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
   <button id="carousel-right" class="nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
   <slot name="carousel-content" class="slider" style=""></slot>

</template>

<template id="carouselContentTemplate">
   <style>
      .item {
          width: 250px;
          padding: 1em;
          height: 300px;
          margin: 0.5em;
          display: inline-table;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          background-color: #fff;
      }

      .item.product .c-rating {
          transform: scale(0.6);
      }
      .item.product .rating {
          margin-bottom: .2rem;
      }
      .item.product .total-avg span {
          margin-right: .4rem;
          color: #be5a0e;
          font-weight: 600;
      }

      .item.product .valuations {
         display: flex;
         line-height: 1.5rem;
         margin-left: 5rem;
      }

      .rating { display:none; }

      .image{
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .topic-1 .price label {
          text-decoration: line-through;
          font-weight: 400;
          margin-right: 6px;
          color: #666;
          font-size: 13px;
      }
   </style>
   <div class="item product">
      <slot name="liga">
         <slot name="imagen" class="thumbnails image">N/D</slot>
         <div class="box topic-1">
            <div class="heading ellipsis">
               <slot name="nombre-producto">NOMBRE DE PRODUCTO</slot>
            </div>
            <div class="rating">
               <div class="review flex">
                  <div class="total-avg">
                     <span><slot name="calificacion">CALIFICACION</slot></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating">
                     <ul class="c-rating">
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print left" data-index="0"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print" data-index="1"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print left" data-index="2"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print" data-index="3"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print left" data-index="4"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print" data-index="5"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print left" data-index="6"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print" data-index="7"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print left" data-index="8"></li>
                        <li class="c-rating__item_print" data-index="9"></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="valuations">
                     <slot name="valoracion" >Sin Valoraciones</slot>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price right">
               <label></label>
               <slot name="precio">PRECIO</slot>
            </div>
         </div>
      </slot>
   </div>
</template>


<div id="wrapp">
   <div class="deals">
      <div class="heading mini-title">
         <h2>Fashion 1</h2>
         <div class="rule"></div>
      </div>
      <my-carousel id="carrusel1">
         <div slot="carousel-content" class="carousel relative">
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto1">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 1">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 1</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(1)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$1,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto2">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 2">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 2</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(2)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$2,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto3">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 3">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 3</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(3)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$3,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto4">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 4">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 4</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(4)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$4,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto5">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 5">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 5</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(5)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$5,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto6">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 6">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 6</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(6)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$6,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto7">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 7">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 7</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(7)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$7,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
         </div>
      </my-carousel>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapp-2">
   <div class="deals-2">
      <div class="heading mini-title">
         <h2>Fashion 2</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
      </div>
      <my-carousel id="carrusel2">
         <div slot="carousel-content">
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto1">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 1">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 1</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(1)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$1,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto2">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 2">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 2</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(2)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$2,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
            <my-carousel-item>
               <a slot="liga" href="producto1">
                  <img slot="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tu producto aquí 3">
                  <h2 slot="nombre-producto">Tu producto aquí 3</h2>
                  <span slot="calificacion">0.0</span>
                  <span slot="valoracion">(3)</span>
                  <em slot="precio" class="item-price">$3,00</em>
               </a>
            </my-carousel-item>
         </div>
      </my-carousel>
   </div>
</div>
```