# ¿Cómo enviar datos automáticamente al manipular el campo input al igual que los botones AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo los siguientes campo `input` al cual envió automáticamente información vía `ajax` cuando realizo algún cambio `ajax` lo recibe sin ningún problema pero solo funciona con el primer campo `input` con el segundo campo `input` no funciona, no me actualiza las cantidades de dicho producto, cabe recalcar que pueden ser más campo `input`.

Otro problema es que no detecta cambio cuando utilizo el botón [disminuir o incrementar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485750/aumentar-o-disminuir-valores-en-el-campo-input-no-funciona-al-cambiar-el-orden-d/485755#485755) es decir que no se ejecuta `ajax` solamente se ejecuta cuando existe manipulación de la entrada del campo `input` manualmente.

```
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input id="quantity"
        type="text"
        name="qtyupdate[1][color-blue][XXL]"
        value="1"
        class="quantity"
        autocomplete="off"
        data-validation="number"
        data-validation-allowing="float">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min">
</div>
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input id="quantity"
        type="text"
        name="qtyupdate[1][color-red][XL]"
        value="1"
        class="quantity"
        autocomplete="off"
        data-validation="number"
        data-validation-allowing="float">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min">
</div>
```

Este es mi código `ajax` estoy utilizando `jQuery`, ¿Qué cambios debo emplear para que funcione correctamente y, no presente los problemas que estoy presentando?

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){

        $('#quantity').keyup(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var formData = [];
            $('input[name^="qtyupdate"]').each(function() {
                formData.push(this.value);
            });
            var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

            var url = "/item_cart.php";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                let res = JSON.parse(data);
                if(res.status){
                    $("#wrapp-basket").load(" #wrapp-basket").fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#qty").load(" #qty").fadeIn('slow');
                    $('.success').fadeIn();
                    $('.success').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                    $.getScript("/assets/js/ajax_coupon.min.js");
                    //return false
                } else {
                    $('.error').fadeIn();
                    $('.error').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                }
            })
            .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
            })
        });
    });
});
```

> Los `input` pueden ser varios ya que es un `input` que se genera automáticamente por cada producto agregado al carro de la compra, por decir si agrego 20 productos al carro de la compra se me va generar 20 `input` ya que el mismo es el encargado de actualizar cuantas unidades quiere por cada producto. También existe una clase con el mismo nombre por si de utilidad `class="quantity"` adjunto imagen como referencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Básicamente tu primer problema es que tienes varios elementos con el mismo `id`. Este valor debe ser **único** en cada documento

Comment: @PabloLozano también tengo una clase con el mismo `class="quantity"` nombre ¿Si lo uso con la clase funcionara de manera individual o no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer punto, es que si deseas que un código funcione para múltiples `input` o uso, no debes usar `id` los `id` son únicos además no debería repetirse en la misma página, entonces tenemos que eliminar `id="quantity"` y, dejar solo la clase `class="quantity"`

Ahora vamos a reemplazar esto:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(evt) {
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
$(this).find('.quantity').keyup(function(evt) {
```

El selector [`$(this)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/), nos permite posicionarnos en un determinado elemento e interactuar con los elementos hijo.

Y, complementamos con [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) devuelve el método de elementos descendientes del elemento seleccionado. Un descendiente es un niño, nieto, bisnieto, y así sucesivamente. Para atravesar solamente un solo nivel hacia abajo el árbol `DOM` (para volver hijos directos), utilice los [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) método.

Answer (score 0):

Tus  **inputs** tiene el mismo **id** como lo dicen en los comentarios
por lo tanto solo se va obtener el valor del primero,cada id debe ser unico,te recomiendo quitar los id de los input y ponerselo al div general y acceder a los inputs del div general

```
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input 
        type="text"
        name="qtyupdate[1][color-blue][XXL]"
        value="1"
        class="quantity"
        autocomplete="off"
        data-validation="number"
        data-validation-allowing="float">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min">
</div>
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input 
        type="text"
        name="qtyupdate[1][color-red][XL]"
        value="1"
        class="quantity"
        autocomplete="off"
        data-validation="number"
        data-validation-allowing="float">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min">
</div>
```

.js

```
$(function () {
  $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#quantity1").keyup(function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var formData = [];
      $('input[name^="qtyupdate"]').each(function () {
        formData.push(this.value);
      });
      var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

      var url = "/item_cart.php";
      sendAjax(formData, url);
    });

    $("#quantity2").keyup(function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var formData = [];
      $('input[name^="qtyupdate"]').each(function () {
        formData.push(this.value);
      });
      var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

      var url = "/item_cart.php";
      sendAjax(formData, url);
    });
    function sendAjax(formData, url) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
      })
        .done(function (data) {
          let res = JSON.parse(data);
          if (res.status) {
            $("#wrapp-basket").load(" #wrapp-basket").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#qty").load(" #qty").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".success").fadeIn();
            $(".success").html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            $.getScript("/assets/js/ajax_coupon.min.js");
            //return false
          } else {
            $(".error").fadeIn();
            $(".error").html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
          }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
          console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
          console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hola, esta alternativa no me conviene, en primer lugar porque aquellos `input` los genera el carro de la compra es decir por cada producto agregado al carrito de la compra se va crear el mismo `input` para cada producto lo único que va cambiar de ese `input` son los valores de `value` y los atributos `name` cabe recalcar que también dispongo de una clase con el mismo nombre del `id` por si ayuda en algo `class="quantity"`

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta, saludos.